# What case can the template of Apache IoTDB be modified?

Tags: templates, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I modify the template in Apache IoTDB using `session.addAlignedMeasurementInTemplate()` statement, a prompt mentioned ·StatementExecutionException:300: Modify template has not been supported. I want to know in what scenarios the template in IoTDB can be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modify template function can only be used for version later or equal to Version 1.2 of Apache IoTDB, so you can see if you need to update your IoTDB version.